# How to remove added lines color in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, editor

I'm new to IntelliJ and I just can't find settings option to remove added lines color:

[image]

Comment: Basically, IntelliJ's code insight is trying to tell you that there's something wrong with your file. If you click on the marked area and wait a second or two, you should see "lightbulb" with options - you can either suppress the warning, or fix it.

Comment: See, it found that you misspelled `android:orientation` attribute.

Comment: I think you didn't understood my question.

Comment: Sorry about that. Code insight hints have very similar highlighting. You have three of them in your file, I can see the difference now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The editor's colors are located in Preferences

- Mac OS X: `IntelliJ IDEA > Preferences`
- Windows: `File > Preferences`

You'll find it in `IDE Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General`, look for `Added lines` or find the offending setting.

Uncheck the box

You can filter the preferences in the search bar in the upper left corner.

[image: IDE Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General]

Comment: Settings option is called "Injected language fragment".