# IntelliJ HTML highlighted whitespace

Tags: intellij-idea

I wanted to remove most of the highlights in the HTML editor. I have done for most of them from Editor->Colors & Fonts->HTML.

But I still get random whitespace highlighting as the picture below for various html files. The strange thing is that it does not appear on all files.
Any idea how to turn the "green" highlighting off?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps its the "Injected language fragment", see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20802306/1354590), otherwise you'll probably have to painstakingly look for that light green color as one of the background color of something...

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :
1.setting->Editor>Colors & Fonts>General(I guess all of color settings extend this)
2.setting->Editor>Colors & Fonts>Language Defaults(I guess all of language color setting extend this)

you can inspect the background in this setting.